# could not find GTest but googletest was fetched

Tags: cmake, googletest

I'm using `googletest` in my project. To add it I used the following code to my CMake

```
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG        release-1.8.0
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(googletest)
if(NOT googletest_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(googletest)
  add_subdirectory(${googletest_SOURCE_DIR} ${googletest_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
```

The problem is whenever I build my project I get a following error

```
Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
```

This is caused by this line of code in one of the tests

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
```

I'm not the owner of the test so I can't change this line. I also can't install `googletest` on the machine where we run our tests. The only option is to use it as a dependency. I'm not really sure how to fix this problem.

Based on the reading of [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) page, I tried changing module path

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${googletest_BINARY_DIR}/googletest/generated)
```

But it didn't work.

Has anyone encountered a problem like that? How did you solve it?